# mysql migration data of tables

Tags: mysql, data-migration

Update migrated table id to related tables

I have three 5 tables.

1. user
2. person
3. event
4. task
5. agreement

I have relations as below

1. user has many events
2. ser has many tasks
3. user has many agreements

I have do below changes.

### First Change - Done

Now I have migrated user data into person table using below query.(This works)

```
INSERT INTO person (person_type,company_id,first_name,last_name,password,email,image,is_delete) 
    SELECT "user" as person_type,1 as company_id,first_name,last_name,password,email,image,is_delete
    FROM `user`
```

### Second Change

After migrating user data into person table, i want to update new person_id of person table into event,task,agreement with existing user.

How to do it? Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution that worked for me.

```
1. Event table migration

    UPDATE event,user,person 
    SET event.person_id = person.person_id
    WHERE event.person_id = user.user_id and user.email = person.email


2. Task table migration

    UPDATE task,user,person 
    SET task.person_id = person.person_id
    WHERE task.person_id = user.user_id and user.email = person.email
```

And so on ... for another tables